# How we differentiate between flash memory and SD card memory?

Tags: android

Some android devices has built-in flash memory, and we can check this memory at `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.  But, when we insert an SD card, then the system differentiates these two with `/storage/sdcard0` and `/storage/sdcard1`.

I am not sure whether `/storage/sdcard0` is flash memory or SD card memory.  Could anyone provide any explanation as to which is which?

Answer (score 2):

Use the method `Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()` to determine if it's a removable SD card or not.

Edit for clarification:

Consider the following method:

```
public enum ExternalStorageStatus { 
    READ_WRITE , READ_ONLY, NONE
}

public static ExternalStorageStatus checkExternalStorageStateAvailable(){
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return ExternalStorageStatus.READ_WRITE;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return ExternalStorageStatus.READ_ONLY;
    } else {
        return ExternalStorageStatus.NONE;
    }
}
```

The method `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` returns the current state of your storage.  If no REAL external storage (i.e. a medium in which `isExternalStorageRemoveable()` == false), then this returns the current state of your internal storage.  If `isExternalStorageRemoveable()` == true, then getExternalStorageState() returns the state of your removable SD card.

Actual external storage is prioritized.

Comment: Hi,problem is to decide this, when both are available in the device.

Comment: See edit for clarification.  If a REAL external storage is available (i.e. a removeable SD card), then the system will return your application's file access permission for that, not the internal SD card.  Otherwise, it'll return your read write permissions for your onboard SD card.  So, the system prioritizes real external storage, then defaults to onboard storage.

Comment: It provides read-write permission for both flash memory and sdcard memory.

Comment: Flash memory is the inbuilt storage and it is seperate from system storage.so our application has read/write permssions  for it. any help to resolve this issue.